# c# mongodb how to update Dictionary<enum, int>

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

My simplified setup is:

```
public class User
{
    public Dictionary<UserProperty, int> Properties;
}

public enum UserProperty
{
    // A lot of properties
}

public class DatabaseManager
{
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new EnumSerializer<UserProperty>(BsonType.String));
    static IMongoCollection<User> Users;

    public async Task UpdateUserProperty(User user, UserProperty prop, int value)
    {
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Where(u => u.Id == user.id);
        var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set(u => u.Properties[prop], value);
        await Users.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update); // throws exception
    }
}
```

I can do a replace operation, and the keys get serialized as strings, but whenever I call `UpdateUserProperty`, I get the error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for `u => u.Properties.get_Item(value(DatabaseManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0).prop)`

How do I fix it?

UPDATE: A workaround I came up with was to replace the lambda expression with `"UserProperties." + prop.ToString()`, but this doesn't provide the compile-time safety and error handling I want

Comment: Is `User.Properties` a public field or a property-getter?

Comment: User.Properties is a public field

Comment: Change it to a property with `{ get; set; }` and see what happens. Most serialization libraries for .NET require properties, not fields.

Comment: `public Dictionary<UserProperty, int> Properties { get; set; }` throws the same exception

Comment: From what I can tell, MongoDB doesn't support using custom enum types as dictionary keys, you can only use `Int32` indexes into lists/arrays and `String` keys in dictionaries (AFAIK).

Comment: No, I've successfully serialized the keys as strings, but the issue is specifically with the update's lambda expression.